# Swing - huge spaces between objects

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I am creating a program using java swing components. when using the components i am creating a text editor. i am using buttons instead of a menu to be able to load/save. when i am trying to implemet theese buttons i get some wierd spacing issues. i have made my code so that there is a panel with the buttons and a text editor by itself. when using this i get a huge spacing between the two objects. PS. the window that the text editor is in is a grid layout.

Here is the code:
    package main;

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TextEditor {
public static void start(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Text editor");
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 50);
    JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();

    buttons.add(saveButton);

    f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1,10,10));
    f.add(buttons);
    f.add(textArea);

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1,10,10));
f.add(buttons);
f.add(textArea);
```

To:

```
f.setLayout(new BorderLayout(3,3));
f.add(buttons, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
f.add(textArea);
```